# Populating jQuery accordion with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have searched around but have not been able to find a good answer to my problem.

I am taking simple object and filling out the divs and headers with this data.

The data gets added but the accordion does not run(Source code tells me everything is where it needs to be). I have ran $("#accordion").accordion(); both before and after the code that is getting the json data

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>jQuery Accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="accordion" class="container">

     </div>



<script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
}).done(function(data) {
    let theData = Object.keys(data).length;
    //console.log(theData);

    for(let i = 0; i < theData; i++) {
        // Making sure I am loading correct data
        console.log(Object.keys(data)[i] + ": " + Object.values(data)[i]);

        $("#accordion").append("<h3>" + Object.keys(data)[i] + "</h3><div><p>" + Object.values(data)[i] + "</p></div>");
    }

})

$("#accordion").accordion();
```

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous, try putting `$("#accordion").accordion();` directly after the loop

Comment: This was perfect @Souleste. Thank you!